# Select records where there are more than one value in one of the fields

Tags: sql, sql-server

Could someone please help me with narrowing down my results? 
Three tables facility, sample, location. With the code below, I get expected results but I would like to show only the records where the matrix code has more that one result (>1). In the example below, I would like to show only location code 0689.

```
SELECT DISTINCT f.facility_code, 
                l.sys_loc_code, 
                l.loc_type, 
                s.matrix_code
FROM dt_sample s join dt_location l on l.facility_id = s.facility_id AND l.sys_loc_code = s.sys_loc_code 
JOIN dt_facility f on f.facility_id = l.facility_id
WHERE l.loc_type ='TS'
GROUP BY f.facility_code, l.sys_loc_code, l.loc_type, s.matrix_code
HAVING COUNT(s.matrix_code)>1
ORDER BY f.facility_code, l.sys_loc_code, s.matrix_code

facility_code   sys_loc_code    loc_type    matrix_code  
DUR03           0687             TS         WATER        
DUR03           0688             TS         WATER        
DUR03           0689             TS         SEDIMENT     
DUR03           0689             TS         SW           
DUR03           0689             TS         WATER
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

One option using `exists()` to check if a different `matrix_code` exists for a given `facility_id` and `sys_loc_code`:

```
select distinct 
    f.facility_code
  , l.sys_loc_code
  , l.loc_type
  , s.matrix_code
from dt_sample s
  inner join dt_location l 
    on l.facility_id = s.facility_id 
   and l.sys_loc_code = s.sys_loc_code
  inner join dt_facility f
   on f.facility_id = l.facility_id
where l.loc_type = 'TS'
  and exists (
    select 1
    from dt_sample i
    where i.facility_id  =  s.facility_id
      and i.sys_loc_code =  s.sys_loc_code
      and i.matrix_code  <> s.matrix_code
  )
order by 
    f.facility_code
  , l.sys_loc_code
  , s.matrix_code
```

Comment: I've never used exists() before. Does exactly what I need. Thank you.